# How to initialize tensor object by preserving ? (None) entry?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Say I have a tensor object `h1 = (?, 256)`.

How can I initialize `h1` as `h1 = (?, zeros(256))` by preserving '?' (None) entry?

(i.e. initialize `h1[1] = zeros(256)`, leaving 'None' as it is)

My code:

```
h1 = np.zeros((h1.shape[0], h1.shape[1]))    
entryh1[1] = np.zeros(256)
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you write the initialization of h1 to clarify the '?'

Comment: try this `h1=(None,numpy.zeros(256))` . trying `h1[1]=np.zeros(256)` will not work because tuple doesn't support item assignment

Comment: h1 is "Tensor("bidirectional_1", shape=(?, 256), dtype=float32).  After h1=(None,numpy.zeros(256)) and feeding this h1 into one of LSTM's state inputs, it gives:  AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get_shape'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the backend function `zeros_like` which will achieve exactly what you want, let's wrap it around a `Lambda` layer so you can pass it to other layers:

```
import keras.backend as K
# ...
gen_zeros = Lambda(lambda x: K.zeros_like(x), name='gen_zeros')
h1_zeros = = gen_zeros(h1) # will give zeros of h1.shape
```

You can check the [documentation](https://keras.io/backend/) for more information on the functions available in the backend which you can use in custom layers.

Comment: Thanks. The reason why I need this is to reduce input numbers of my module as small as possible (although this may make the model summary a little bit lousy).